# Django Form Does Not Validate With Correct Files

Tags: python, html, django, forms, validation

```
class RentalImageForm(forms.Form):
    images = forms.FileField(validators=
        [FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'],
        message='Only JPG, JPEG, PNG, and GIF files are allowed.')])

@login_required
def createListing(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        createListingForm = RentalForm(request.POST)
        if request.FILES.getlist('images'):
            uploaded_files = request.FILES.getlist('images')
            print(uploaded_files)

            for files in uploaded_files:
                rental_image_form = RentalImageForm({'images':files})
                if rental_image_form.is_valid():
                    print('VALID')
                    
                
                else:
                    print(rental_image_form.errors)





 <input
        type="file"
        name="images"
        accept="image/*"
        required
        multiple
        id="id_images"
      />

_____________________________________________________
```

I am trying to validate each file I upload to my input and then put them in a loop to verify that all files are in correct extensions. Even when my extensions are all correct my Rental Image Form gives out false when I check with .is_valid(). Overall I have checked and seen that my images files are correctly uploaded but when it comes to validating the form it fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect images as input, maybe it's better to use [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) instead.
As for the errors, maybe check the [encoding type](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_form_enctype.asp) on the form that contains the input element.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).